# How to Get Static Qt Build with any extra module. Eg: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: += serialport

Tags: qt, static, windows-7, serial-port, windows-embedded

trying to use serialport with a static build of qt and keep getting this error when running qmake or build.

error: Unknown module(s) in QT: += serialport

Using:

- QT creator 5.5.1
- Windows 7
- Commercial Licence
- QT Static build 5.13.0
- Got a barebones test project with completely standard .pro file.

Things Attempted:

- Adding QT: += serialport in pro file
- Building Qt5SerialPort on its own
- Adding INCLUDEPATH with path to the built Qt5SerialPort
- Adding built Qt5SerialPort Libs to pro file
- Adding built Qt5SerialPort to static qtbase's include and libs
  folders and rebuilding static qt with jom
- Tried other things that have been demonstrated to work on solved
  questions:
  https://forum.qt.io/topic/57299/project-error-unknown-module-s-in-qt-serialport/2 ; done this step for step (kinda, i'm not using minGW cos commercial), didn't work

this is what the .pro file looks like:

```
QT       += core gui \
         serialport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testserialport
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Expecting to run qmake and be able to use the #include files for serialport and in the future be able to do the same with other modules for static Qt builds.

Cheers

Comment: Can I see your configure command? I built a static Qt library, and I have the serialport. You can look at my configure command here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/102303/issues-building-static-qt/19

Comment: I've been using ```configure -debug-and-release -static -commercial -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests```. I'll have a go with the one on the link cheers

Comment: After running jom the build quits with this error: `jom: C:\Q
t\5.13.0\Src\qtbase\src\Makefile [sub-qdbusxml2cpp-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\qtbase\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.13.0\Src\Makefile [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
`

Comment: I don't know what that means. Did you run configure on a fresh source tree? A couple of times, I've failed to untar a fresh copy before configuring, and it can cause really weird errors.

Comment: So along with your configure command and python2.7 (i had 3.7) on the path, it is now working, thanks :)